# Force load of web.xml before Spring WebApplicationInitializer classes

Tags: spring, spring-4

How can I be sure that `web.xml` in a web application is loaded before any Spring [WebApplicationInitializer](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) classes?

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html) of `WebApplicationInitializer`:

> `WEB-INF/web.xml` and `WebApplicationInitializer` use are not mutually
>   exclusive; for example, web.xml can register one servlet, and a
>   WebApplicationInitializer can register another. An initializer can
>   even modify registrations performed in web.xml through methods such as
>   ServletContext.getServletRegistration(String)...

So according to this I might assume that `web.xml` is loaded before any `WebApplicationInitializer` classes. This I have not observed to be the case.

I am providing an implementation of `WebApplicationInitializer` and what I want to do in the code is the following so that if a servlet has already been registered *in a web.xml file* then I do not attempt to register it for a second time:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {

    if(servletContext.getServletRegistration(MY_SERVLET_NAME) == null) {
        // Servlet not already registered in web.xml so register it now
        servletContext.addServlet(..etc)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. My `if` check was erroneous leading me to think that web.xml was loaded after. For reference I'll leave the question but the ordering does seem to be `web.xml` first followed by any `WebApplicationInitializer` classes.